# How to call the attribute inside the static block?

Tags: product-attribute, magento-1, static-block, ce-1.9.2.4

I want to Create tabs to switch between contents inside the Product details page and call the attribute ( Description of the product) inside one of the tab content.( That attribute value should be unique for each product.)

So I created a static block to implement it like this:

```
    <div class="details-tab">
    <ul class="tab-links">
        <li class="active"><a href="#tab1">Tab 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab2">Tab 2</a></li>
    </ul>

    <div class="tab-content">
        <div id="tab1" class="tab active">
            <p>{{block type="core/template"  template="catalog/product/view/description.phtml"}}<p>  
        </div>

        <div id="tab2" class="tab">
            <p>Tab #2 content goes here!</p>
            <p> online store.</p>
        </div>

    </div>
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('.details-tab .tab-links a').on('click', function(e)  {
        var currentAttrValue = jQuery(this).attr('href');

        // Show/Hide Tabs
        jQuery('.details-tab ' + currentAttrValue).show().siblings().hide();

        // Change/remove current tab to active
        jQuery(this).parent('li').addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');

        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
</script>
```

But am getting error like:

`Fatal error: Call to a member function getDescription() on null`.

How to resolve this. Where Have I went wrong?

Comment: Do you have a product loaded in the CMS Block? What exactly do you want to display? Provide more details about your issue and / or example code

Comment: @alex Dinca kindly see my updated question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply replace every instance of `$this->getProduct()` with `Mage::registry('current_product')` inside `description.phtml`.

Alternative (somewhat cleaner):
Make this your first line in `description.phtml`:
`<?php $this->setProduct(Mage::registry('current_product')) ?>`

Comment: I guess you beat me to it :P

Answer (score 1):

1. You cannot use {{block ... }} in phtml.

   Reffer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10647650/how-to-call-magento-block-in-phtml-template) on how to call blocks in phtml files.
   In your case, use something like

   `<?php echo $this->getLayout()
   ->createBlock('cms/block')
   ->setBlockId('description')
   ->setTemplate('catalog/product/view/description.phtml')
   ->toHtml() ?>`
2. In your description.phtml you call `$this->getProduct()` but `$this` calls the class of the block, which is `core/template`and core/template does not have a function `getProduct()` so .... 
   In order to resolve this you can

   1. Set the block as `catalog/product_view_attributes` or
   2. Try replacing `$this->getProduct()` with `Mage::registry('current_product')`

Comment: I gave this code in Static block at admin panel not in phtml.And my description.phtml code is:  `
<?php $_description = $this->getProduct()->getDescription(); ?>
<?php if ($_description): ?>
    <h2><?php echo $this->__('Details') ?></h2>
    <div class="std">
        <?php echo $this->helper('catalog/output')->productAttribute($this->getProduct(), $_description, 'description') ?>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>`